# Best way to output 100,000 records from PL/SQL program into XML file

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I'm new to XML but have been been given a task to output a test set of 100,000 records to an XML file, this will be a much bigger file in future. Within each record there is subsets of child data that needs also to output to the file (see a structure of code below).

I'm trying to find the best solution to this dbms_xmldom but looking at forums this is an outdated tool but I know there is XMLElement but I think this only works in SQL and not PL/SQL.

Is there something else that works in PL/SQL other than dbms_xmldom that is just as good or should I stick to what I'm doing. The tool has to output each record to an output file.

The current version of the database is 11g release 1.

Any advice would be great thanks in advance.

```
  BEGIN

  For r_prod_rec IN c_prod_rec
  LOOP
    output process master record to XML file

    For r_prod_child1_rec IN c_prod_child1_rec(r_prod_rec.id)
    LOOP
         output process child record from table1 to XML file
    END LOOP

    For r_prod_child2_rec IN c_prod_child2_rec(r_prod_rec.id)
    LOOP
         output process child record table2 to XML file
    END LOOP

  END LOOP

  END
```

Comment: Why are you dismissing SQL as a solution?

Comment: I agree with MT0 can't you just generate in sql and export?  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1600

Comment: `xmlelement` and other XML functions (like `xmlforest`) work perfectly well also in PL/SQL. Why do you think they are not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE parents ( ID, Attr1, Attr2 ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'A.' || LEVEL, 'B.' || LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

CREATE TABLE children ( ID, Attr1, Parent_ID ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'C.' || LEVEL, CASE WHEN LEVEL <= 3 THEN 1
                                  WHEN LEVEL <= 6 THEN 2
                                  WHEN LEVEL <= 8 THEN 4
                                                  ELSE 5
                             END FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 9;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "Root",
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             "Parent",
             XMLATTRIBUTES(
               p.id,
               p.attr1 AS "A",
               p.attr2 AS "B"
             ),
             c.child_xml
           )
         )
       ).getClobVal() AS xml
FROM   parents p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT parent_id,
                XMLAGG(
                  XMLELEMENT(
                    "Child",
                    XMLATTRIBUTES( id ),
                    attr1
                  )
                ) AS child_xml
         FROM   children
         GROUP BY parent_id
       ) c
       ON ( p.id = c.parent_id );
```

**Output**:

```
XML
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Root><Parent ID="1" A="A.1" B="B.1"><Child ID="1">C.1</Child><Child ID="2">C.2</Child>
<Child ID="3">C.3</Child></Parent><Parent ID="2" A="A.2" B="B.2"><Child ID="4">C.4</Child>
<Child ID="5">C.5</Child><Child ID="6">C.6</Child></Parent><Parent ID="3" A="A.3" B="B.3">
</Parent><Parent ID="4" A="A.4" B="B.4"><Child ID="7">C.7</Child><Child ID="8">C.8</Child>
</Parent><Parent ID="5" A="A.5" B="B.5"><Child ID="9">C.9</Child></Parent></Root>
```

If you want to use this in PL/SQL then just do:

```
DECLARE
  p_xml CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT ...
  INTO   p_xml
  FROM   ...;

  -- Then use the xml value.
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has package DBMS_XMLGEN. You can use it to conver query result into xmltype. In my example I'm also using  "CURSOR Expressions".

```
declare   
     v_xml xmltype;
begin    
     v_xml := DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE ('select cursor(select x.COLUMN_NAME,x.DATA_TYPE from user_tab_columns x where x.table_name = y.table_name),y.table_name from user_tables y where rownum < 3');
    dbms_output.put_line(v_xml.getClobVal());
end;
```